# How do I shift my thinking to 'vectorize my computation' more than using 'for-loops'?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, vectorization

This is definitely more of a notional question, but I wanted to get others expertise input on this topic at SO. Most of my programming is coming from [Numpy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) arrays lately. I've been matching items in two or so arrays that are different in sizes. Most of the time I will go to a for-loop or even worst, nested for-loop. I'm ultimately trying to avoid using for-loops as I try to gain more experience in Data Science because for-loops perform slower.

I am well aware of Numpy and the pre-defined cmds I can research, but for those of you whom are experienced, do you have a **general school of thought when you iterate through something?**

Something similar to the following:

```
small_array = np.array(["a", "b"])
big_array = np.array(["a", "b", "c", "d"])

for i in range(len(small_array)):
    for p in range(len(big_array)):
        if small_array[i] == big_array[p]:
            print "This item is matched: ", small_array[i]
```

I'm well aware there are more than one way to skin a cat with this, but I am interested in others approach and way of thinking.

Comment: It's best to take a step back and ask yourself, "what do I want to do"? Usually, trying to answer the question in _english_ (or your native tongue) is the first step to formulating a solution.

Comment: Once you have an idea down, try and figure out the _best_ way to have your mental solutions manifest.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not on-topic for SO because it's opinion based. The only way to learn how to vectorized things is to practice; whether that's your own projects or reading some excellent answers on here for a variety of problems e.g. read through Divakar's answers, or MaxU and others.

Comment: For the general way of thinking - Gather info about the tools (go through various NumPy funcs and ufuncs), choose the best ones (practice and play around and see which ones are fast) for different scenarios. For this specific case - Seems `np.searchsorted` could help. The key would always be practice.

Comment: When programming in NumPy, you get best results if you can vectorize your computation — that is, replace explicit loops in Python with whole-array operations in NumPy. This is conceptually very different from ordinary programming in Python, and takes time to learn. So I guess I am trying  to ask for advice on how to go about learning to do it.  Thank you to everyone for your inputs so far!

Comment: If disregarding the opinion-basedness of the question, it might be more suitable for [softwareengineering.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I've been working with array languages for decades (APL, MATLAB, numpy) I can't help with the starting steps.  But I suspect I work mostly from patterns, things I've seen and used in the past.  And I do a lot to experimentation in an interactive session.

To take your example:

```
In [273]: small_array = np.array(["a", "b"])
     ...: big_array = np.array(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
     ...: 
     ...: for i in range(len(small_array)):
     ...:     for p in range(len(big_array)):
     ...:         if small_array[i] == big_array[p]:
     ...:             print( "This item is matched: ", small_array[i])
     ...:             
This item is matched:  a
This item is matched:  b
```

Often I run the iterative case just to get a clear(er) idea of what is desired.

```
In [274]: small_array
Out[274]: 
array(['a', 'b'],
      dtype='<U1')
In [275]: big_array
Out[275]: 
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

I've seen this before - iterating over two arrays, and doing something with the paired values.  This is a kind of `outer` operation.  There are various tools, but the one I like best makes use of `numpy` broadcasting.  It turn one array into a (n,1) array, and use it with the other (m,) array

```
In [276]: small_array[:,None]
Out[276]: 
array([['a'],
       ['b']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

The result of (n,1) operating with (1,m) is a (n,m) array:

```
In [277]: small_array[:,None]==big_array
Out[277]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Now I can take an `any` or `all` reduction on either axis:

```
In [278]: _.all(axis=0)
Out[278]: array([False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [280]: __.all(axis=1)
Out[280]: array([False, False], dtype=bool)
```

I could also use `np.where` to reduce that boolean to indices.

---

Oops, I should have used `any`

```
In [284]: (small_array[:,None]==big_array).any(0)
Out[284]: array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
In [285]: (small_array[:,None]==big_array).any(1)
Out[285]: array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Having played with this I remember that there's a `in1d` that does something similar

```
In [286]: np.in1d(big_array, small_array)
Out[286]: array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

But when I look at the code for `in1d` (see the `[source]` link  in the docs), I see that, in some cases it actually iterates on the small array:

```
In [288]: for x in small_array:
     ...:     print(x==big_array)
     ...:     
[ True False False False]
[False  True False False]
```

Compare that to `Out[277]`.  `x==big_array` compares a scalar with an array.  In `numpy`, doing something like `==`, `+`, `*` etc with an array and scalar is easy, and should become second nature.  Doing the same thing with 2 arrays of matching shapes is the next step.  And from there do it with broadcastable shapes.

In other cases it use `np.unique` and `np.argsort`.

This pattern of creating a higher dimension array by broadcasting the inputs against each other, and then combining values with some sort of reduction (any, all, sum, mean, etc) is very common.

Comment: Thanks for understanding! This is a common conceptual difficulty when learning to use NumPy effectively. Normally, data processing in Python is best expressed in terms of iterators, keep memory usage low, maximize opportunities for parallelism with the I/O system, and to provide for reuse and combination of parts of algorithms.
But NumPy turns all that inside out: the best approach is to express the algorithm as a sequence of whole-array operations, to minimize the amount of time spent in the slow Python interpreter and maximize the amount of time spent in fast compiled NumPy routines.

Answer (score 1):

I will interpret your question in a more specific way:

1. How do I quit using index variables?
2. How do I start writing list comprehensions instead of normal loops"?

To quit using index variables, the key is to understand that "for" in Python is not the "for" of other languagues. It should be called "for each".

```
for x in small_array:
    for y in big_array:
        if x == y:
            print "This item is matched: ", x
```

That's much better.

I also find myself in situations where I would write code with normal loops (or actually do it) and then start wondering whether it would be clearer and more elegant with a list comprehension.

List comprehensions are really a domain-specific language to create lists, so the first step would be to learn its basics. A typical statement would be:

```
l = [f(x) for x in list_expression if g(x)]
```

Meaning "give me a list of f(x), for all x out of list_expression that meet condition g"

So you could write it in this way:

```
matched = [x for x in small_array if x in big_array]
```

Et *voilà*, you are on the road to pythonic style!

Comment: This is a good Python pattern, though I think the OP is aiming for something beyond that.  `vectorization` is more of a `numpy` concept.  But if you are starting with lists, it often is faster to stick with the lists and list comprehensions.  Arrays can be fast, but creating them from lists is time consuming.

Comment: I agree. And since numpy relies on Python patterns, it will be useful to acquire them before learning numpy (besides, since numpy arrays are iterable, it would still use similar techniques).

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you better use vectorized stuff to speed up. Learning it is a long path. You have to get used with matrices multiplication if you aren't already. Once you are, try to translate your data into matrix and see which multiplication you can do. Usually you can't do what you want with this and have super-matrices (more than 2D dimensions). That's where numpy get useful.

Numpy provides some functions like `np.where`, know how to use them. Know shortcuts like `small_array[small_array == 'a'] = 'z'`. Try to combine numpy functions with nativ pythons (map, filter...).

To handle multi-dimension matrix, there's no seccret, practice and use paper to understand what you're doing. But over 4 dimensions it starts getting very tricky.

Answer (score 0):

For loops are not necessarily slow. That's a matlab nonsense spread through time because of matlab's own fault. Vectorization **is** "for" looping but in a lower level. You need to get a handle on what kind of data and architecture you are working in and which kind of function your are executing over your data.