# Optimize a function call with array index

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function with the following prototype:

```
def fun(signal,const):
    n = len(signal);
    index = np.arange(n);
    F = np.sum(signal*np.exp((-2*np.pi*np.complex(1j)*const*index)/n));
    return F;
```

The end result I would like to have is the output of:

```
for i in np.arange(4):
    out[i] = fun(inp,i)
```

How could I get this result without the loop and without vectorize fo a lambda function since my understanding is that vectorize uses also a loop. I am looking for a function from the numpy family to achieve this.

I tried the following without luck:

```
b= np.array([0,1,2,3]);
print(fun(inp,b));
```

The problem with the above is it passes the entire array where what I need is passing just the current index.

Comment: How about `print([DFT(inp, x) for x in b])`?

Comment: I'm not able to understand what your issue is. You suggest that you want the output of a `for` loop, your question title suggests you want to vectorize this calculation, but then you say you want to avoid vectorization. Are you aiming for speed? Passing the whole list to a function and iterating in the function is faster than the function call overhead of calling for every index in your loop. Can you please include a self-contained example? `inp` and `out` for example are not defined.

Comment: Can you change the function to work with `np.arange(4)`, as opposed to a scalar `i`?  WIthout knowing anything about `DFT` we can't suggest an improvement.

Comment: Thx for your comments. I updated the question. Hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one little change `fun` can work with a array `const`; add `axis` parameter to the `sum`:

```
def fun(signal,const):
    n = len(signal);
    index = np.arange(n);
    F = np.sum(signal*np.exp((-2*np.pi*np.complex(1j)*const*index)/n),axis=-1);
    return F;

In [126]: signal = np.arange(10)*.1    
In [139]: for i in range(4):
     ...:     print(fun(signal,i))     
(4.5+0j)
(-0.5+1.53884176859j)
(-0.5+0.688190960236j)
(-0.5+0.363271264003j)
```

I generate the same numbers by providing a column vector:

```
In [142]: fun(signal, np.arange(4)[:,None])
Out[142]: 
array([ 4.5+0.j        , -0.5+1.53884177j, -0.5+0.68819096j,
       -0.5+0.36327126j])
```

This `const` multiplies with `index` to produce a (4,n) array:

```
In [143]: np.arange(4)[:,None]*np.arange(10)
Out[143]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18],
       [ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27]])
```

That multplies the other scalars and the (n,) `signal`, staying (4,n).  Sum on the last dimension, and the result is a (4,) array.

I explained this way of thinking recently in:

[How do I shift my thinking to 'vectorize my computation' more than using 'for-loops'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254563/how-do-i-shift-my-thinking-to-vectorize-my-computation-more-than-using-for-lo)